# Is there an iOS timelapse app that saves frames to camera roll?

Tags: software-recommendation, ios-appstore, camera

I'm looking for an app that will save individual frames to the camera roll as it goes, at something like a 1-5 second interval. I'm having trouble finding any apps that don't expect you to use them to make the final video; I'd rather do that at home on the computer where I can use the images along with the ones off the SLR.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The pro version of Joby's camera app "GorillaCam Pro" will do this.

Comment: I had honestly forgotten about this post. I notice the on/off switch for this feature is (currently) in the second screenshot for the GorillaCamPro app, so for $2 that'll be nice for the next time I do timelapse work. Thanks! :)